# Showing a useful result for Wisharts and Multivariate Beta random matrices

Tags: wishart-distribution, cholesky-decomposition, random-matrix, jacobian

Let $\mathbf{A} \sim \text{Wishart}_m\left(k_a,\mathbf{V} \right)$ and $\mathbf{B} \sim \text{Wishart}_m\left(k_b,\mathbf{V} \right)$ be two full rank Wishart random matrices. Define 
$$
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}
$$
and 
$$
\mathbf{U} = (\mathbf{T}^{-1})^{'}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{T}^{-1}
$$
where  $\mathbf{T}'\mathbf{T}$ is the Cholesky decomposition of $\mathbf{S}$. Show

1. $\mathbf{S} \sim \text{Wishart}\left(k_1 + k_2, \mathbf{V} \right)$
2. $\mathbf{U} \sim \text{Matrix Beta}_m\left(\frac{k_1}{2}, \frac{k_2}{2}\right)$, and
3. $\mathbf{S}$ is independent of $\mathbf{U}$.

I'm trying to show it using densities with respect to Lebesgue measure. [Muirhead's book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Aspects_of_Multivariate_Statistical_Theo.html?id=5xrvAAAAMAAJ) goes through a lot of this stuff, but appeals to k-forms, which I'm not very comfortable with, and I'm trying to avoid at the moment. Actually, I think this book even *defines* the matrix-variate beta distribution using this. Apparently it's also true in the not-full-rank case (c.f. [Uhlig 1994](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176325375)), but I'd like to tackle the simpler version first.

[This book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1196285102#toc) looks pretty good, so I'm working through it at the moment.

Comment: There is also this article that provides the singular multivariate beta distributions with respect to Lebesgue measure: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-31/issue-5/Singular-Wishart-and-multivariate-beta-distributions/10.1214/aos/1065705118.full